# Cython Pure Python Mode: Not a type

Tags: python, types, cython, cythonize

I have a class object that I am trying to cythonize, I added some decorators for a start. My actual class is slightly more complex, I simplified it for the example.

```
from typing import Tuple

import cv2
import cython
import numpy as np

@cython.cclass
class Theia:
    def __init__(self, change_time: int, rho: float) -> None:
        self.change_time = change_time
        self.temporal_window = 4 * self.change_time
        self.rho = rho

    @cython.cfunc
    def preprocess_image(self, img: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        grey_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).astype(float)

        return grey_image
```

However, when I compile, I get the following error

> ### Error compiling Cython file:
>
> ```
> preprocess_image(img: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
>                                       ^
> ```
>
> ---
>
> my_file.py:49:22: Not a type

How can I fix this issue?

I compile using a setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        [
            "my_file.py",
        ],
        annotate=True,
    ),  # enables generation of the html annotation file
)
```

and running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Note: This error also occurs with types `None, bool, Tuple`, solutions for these types are also welcome

Comment: How did you import `numpy as np`?

Comment: I edited with the imports. I imported it with `import numpy as np`

Comment: Try adding `cimport numpy as np` below the `import numpy as np` and run again

Comment: I get a syntax error.
`Error compiling Cython file: cimport numpy as np  Syntax error in simple statement list` Note I am using cython in pure python mode and my file is ".py" not ".pyx"

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Cython you're using. Some (but not all) of this may be improved by using the Cython 3 alpha. It also adds a pure Python way of doing `cimport`

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think Cython will be able to do much with the `np.ndarray` type in your code anyway.

Comment: @DavidW, thanks i'll try that version. I oversimplified my code for the question, it is more complex